# overlay when i open/close slide-out menu with different elements

Tags: jquery, overlay

I am using the ShiftNav Pro plugin because I want a slideout menu that pushes the site when opened.

I would like for it to have a dark overlay when opened using the menu button. But then I want it to close using a separate button within the menu.

I used this code to achieve the overlay:

```
jQuery('#shiftnav-toggle-main.shiftnav-toggle-edge-right .shiftnav-toggle-burger').on("click",function() {
  if(jQuery('.overlay').length == 0) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('overlay');
  }
  else {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('overlay');
  }
});
```

But when I click on the **Close menu** button within the menu, instead of just closing the menu, the overlay doesn't disappear. It only disappears when I click outside of the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.

**First** of all, the close button doesn't trigger the code. You have to add the class `.shiftnav-panel-close` as well because this is the class of the close button:

**Second:** you are using the function toggleClass and removeClass. But the toggleClass should be enough, because it removes/adds the class on click. This way you don't need the if/else statement.

**Third:** The 'this' part in `jQuery(this).toggleClass('overlay');` refers to the div you clicked on. So, if you click on the close div with the class `.shiftnav-panel-close`, it toggles the class on this div.
But your '.overlay' class (to show the overlay) is set on the div with id `#shiftnav-toggle-main-button`. So, you should not refer to 'this' but to the div with id `#shiftnav-toggle-main-button`.

**Final code:**

```
$('#shiftnav-toggle-main-button, .shiftnav-panel-close').on('click', function(){ // On click on menu button or close button

    $("#shiftnav-toggle-main-button").toggleClass('overlay'); //Toggle class .overlay

});
```

**JSFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljjyth06/2/

Comment: I actually tried that earlier and it didn't work. It's still giving me the same issue. When I click on the **Close menu** button, the overlay takes over the whole page.

Comment: @Jacqui I understood it wrong. I've updated the answer.